# Why `eval $(minikube docker-env)` (setting docker env vars) does not work in npm script

Tags: node.js, bash, docker, npm, kubernetes

I tried to do `eval $(minikube docker-env)` (enable use of local docker for `minikube`). But noticed it does not actually work.

```
$ npm run kube:docker

> eval $(minikube docker-env)
```

But docker images show my own docker images rather

```
REPOSITORY                                                                    TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
node                                                                          12-alpine           80a733d0cd8c        6 days ago          77.3MB
...
```

But when running outside npm script:

```
$ eval $(minikube docker-env)

$ docker images
REPOSITORY                                TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
k8s.gcr.io/kube-proxy                     v1.14.0             5cd54e388aba        5 weeks ago         82.1MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-apiserver                 v1.14.0             ecf910f40d6e        5 weeks ago         210MB
k8s.gcr.io/kube-scheduler                 v1.14.0             00638a24688b        5 weeks ago         81.6MB
```

The result is correct, where I do see my kubernetes images as expected. Why is that?

Comment: Subshells do not influence the environment of the parent shell; try this experiment: `bash -c 'eval $(minikube docker-env)'; docker images`

Comment: @MatthewLDaniel somehow this didnt seem to help

Comment: @JiewMeng it was not supposed to work, it was just an example of that shell does not inherit environment variables of its childs. In your case "npm run" is child of your shell. Whatever environment variables you define in "npm run" (with minikube docker-env) will influence only the npm run session. It won't have any effect on parent shell. You see what we mean?

Comment: Ah ic ... so there is no way to make it work I guess :( wanted a shorter route to do that haha

Comment: @JiewMeng to make what work? If you're trying to make a shorter `minikube docker-env` command, then a shell alias may do that. If you are automating something in npm, you still can, it just requires running that `eval` in the same shell snippet as the one that will use docker, something like: `{"scripts:{"tag-it":"eval $(minikube docker-env); docker tag the-sha-here the/repo:tag; etc"}}`

Comment: Try create/re-create docker image after running the command $(minikube docker-env). This does not directly answer your question.